# Gatsby-image-background-slider triggers TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of undefined

Tags: reactjs, gatsby

I use `gatsby-image-background-slider` on my project and it triggers `TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of undefined changeIndex src/index.js:111 callback src/index.js:129`.

The same hero worked initially, but during the development, it started giving this error. I have reinstalled packages, tried with a new hello-world-project with the same code.

```
    Hero.js

    import React from "react"
    import { useStaticQuery, graphql } from "gatsby"
    import BackgroundSlider from 'gatsby-image-background-slider'
    
    const Hero = ({ children }) => (
      <>
        <main>{children}</main>
        <BackgroundSlider
          query={useStaticQuery(graphql`
            query {
              backgrounds: allFile (filter: {sourceInstanceName: {eq: "backgrounds"}}){
                nodes {
                  relativePath
                  childImageSharp {
                    fluid (maxWidth: 4000, quality: 100){
                      ...GatsbyImageSharpFluid
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          `)}
          initDelay={2}
          transition={4}
          duration={8}
          images={["picture2.jpg", "picture2.jpg"]}
        >
        </BackgroundSlider>
      </>
    )
    
    export default Hero
```

Do you know what could be causing this?

Comment: Where's the style `prop`?

Comment: I use global css.

Answer (score 1):

[As it's inferred from the documentation](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/plugins/gatsby-image-background-slider/#configured-background-slider) (and from other examples), it seems that adding `initDelay`, `transition` or `duration` `props` is forcing the component to receive also `style` `props`. Since you are not passing it, it breaks the dependency code.

If you don't plan to add any `style` property, you can simply use a dummy styling such as:

```
    <BackgroundSlider
      query={useStaticQuery(graphql`
        query {
          backgrounds: allFile (filter: {sourceInstanceName: {eq: "backgrounds"}}){
            nodes {
              relativePath
              childImageSharp {
                fluid (maxWidth: 4000, quality: 100){
                  ...GatsbyImageSharpFluid
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      `)}
      initDelay={2}
      transition={4}
      duration={8}
      style={{`display: initial`}}
      images={["picture2.jpg", "picture2.jpg"]}
    >
    </BackgroundSlider>
```

---

Since the plugin is low-maintained and doesn't expose better examples, I would suggest using a custom `<div>` structure within [`gatsby-background-image`](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/plugins/gatsby-background-image/) plus another carousel dependency, such as [React Slick Slider](https://react-slick.neostack.com/). Something like:

```
const SimpleSlider=()=> {
  const data = useStaticQuery(graphql`
      query {
          backgrounds: allFile (filter: {sourceInstanceName: {eq: "backgrounds"}}){
              nodes {
                  relativePath
                  childImageSharp {
                      fluid (maxWidth: 4000, quality: 100){
                          ...GatsbyImageSharpFluid
                      }
                  }
              }
          }
      }
  `)

  const settings = {
    dots: true,
    infinite: true,
    speed: 500,
    slidesToShow: 1,
    slidesToScroll: 1
  };

  return <div>
      <h2> Single Item</h2>
      <Slider {...settings}>
        { backgrounds.nodes.map(background =>{
            return <BackgroundImage
              Tag="section"
              className={`yourClassName`}
              fluid={background.childImageSharp.fluid}
              backgroundColor={`#040e18`}
              style={{`height:100%; width:100%`}}
            />
          })}
      </Slider>
    </div>
}
```

Note that without a sandbox, you may need to adapt a little bit of the snippet, especially with the `styles` `prop`, but you get the idea.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Adding style prop does not fix the problem for some reason. It is strange.

Comment: Can you upgrade the package version? Also, what happens is you remove the `initDelay`, `transition`, `duration` and `style` props? Does it keep breaking?

Comment: Sadly, neither solved or changed the error.

Comment: Which version are you using?

Comment: `"gatsby": "^2.26.1",
"gatsby-background-image": "^1.3.1",
"gatsby-image": "^2.9.0",
"gatsby-image-background-slider": "0.0.4",`

Comment: Maybe you can use a normal slider using `gatsby-background-image` + adding the custom `<divs>`. The package you are using has poor fallback and support. I can add some examples if you want

Comment: That sounds the optimal decision. Would be really cool if you could share some examples.

Comment: I get a strange error with that code (even after trying to solve the problem)
`Unexpected token, expected "," (43:8)` pointing at row just before the </slider>. It strangely matches with the wrong opening curly bracket (not in the correct order). Never seen these types of error, I am a bit new.

Comment: It's fixed. I've some elements oddly closed @venni